# What does "Paper in Production" mean?

Tags: publications, conference, ieee

I submitted an accepted conference paper (the camera-ready version) to the IEEE author dashboard as requested by the conference. The paper status has changed from "Submitted" to "In-Production". What does this mean? Is this the final stage before the publication? Or do the IEEE editors also do a final check and perhaps let the authors fix any concerns (if any)?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank you for the link. Is this also apply to IEEE? if so, then yes this answers my question.